# What if we design to rotate batteries along with the DC motor they are powering?

Tags: batteries, dc-motor

I am working on a product design and overwhelmed with an idea that we can design to accommodate the battery pack along with the DC motor and the whole assembly will rotate (imagine it like a rotating wheel powered by a DC motor)

From product design perspective, it's all fine but I want to understand from the experts, what potentially can go wrong in this scenario from technology standpoint. Or if otherwise.

- Motor: DC 1000W Brushless
- Battery pack: 18650 Li-ion 3.7v
- Rotation speed: 30mph

Comment: 30mph does not specify rotational rate ... it specifies linear velocity

Comment: _"What if..."_ questions are not good questions to ask on here. I'm also completely lost in trying to visual this... battery rotating mechanism.

Comment: There is nothing special about rotating the battery except that the controller would probably be rotating also, likely requiring a suitable remote human interface operating system. Since you have presented no credible design details, not much advice is possible. Voting to close.

Comment: I think if you are going to be designing something that goes 30mph and produces 1kW of motion, you shouldn't be asking the experts, you should be the expert.

Comment: Getting the thing balanced would be a significant challenge and special measures need to be taken to account for the centripetal forces. It would also need to be impervious to weather, being flooded, mechanical shock on hitting potholes etc.

Comment: I suppose you are trying to solve some issue by rotating the battery and motor, what is that issue? This seems like an X-Y problem...

Answer (score 1):

Batteries have limited mechanical shock and acceleration ratings.
Beyond a certain limit, electrodes will break inside the battery, and it will catch fire. This is one of the main hazard for electrical vehicles, and that is why batteries are in heavily shielded enclosure.

If you are expecting any large accelerations or strong shocks, which the 1000W or 30Mph numbers suggest, you should take steps to protect your batteries, and putting them in wheels seems like a bad idea.